# how to draw Highcharts in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas

I am new to Three.JS, I want to draw 2d Highchart on a face of the cube. So far I am able to draw a cube and paste a image on the face but not sure how do I do with Highchart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primitive example of rendering charts on the sides of the cube (threejs.org + highcharts.com):

http://goo.gl/ohexxL